# Select columns of a dataframe by row names of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In this example i have a DataFrame (df) with 7 Columns.

df

```
Apple    Banana    Blueberry    Kiwi    Pineapple    Mango    Grapes
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
...      ...       ...          ...     ...          ...      ...
...      ...       ...          ...     ...          ...      ...
```

In my second DataFrame(features) I have one single column containing the Information which columns to choose in my first DataFrame(df). In every turn the amount of rows in DataFrame(features) is random. In the first run it could be Apple, Banana and Blueberry, in the next run it could be Grapes, Mango, Pineapple and Apple.

For example:

Features

```
combined
--------
Apple
Banana
Blueberry
```

What is the most efficient way to minimize df given by the Information of column "combined" in DataFrame(features) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question a little confused, but if I'm right what you want it this:

(I don't know if what you want to do with de dataframe, so I'll just insert it in a list)

```
listDF = []

for fruit in features['combined']:
    listDF.append(df[fruit])
```

Is that what you were looking for?